# Transversal curves and change of direction of vector field along them.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a statement regarding transversal curves and their relation to the vector field that I cannot figure out why it is true. Not even at an intuitive level.

I quote,

"Since the vector field is transverse to the curve $\gamma$ the vectors $v(x)$ for all $x \in \gamma$ all point in the same direction. Else by continuity and mean-value theorem  some $v(x)$ would be parallel to the transversal curve."

Why cant the curve just make a really steep turn after traveling a long way for instance, then come back in the other direction even in small neigbourhood?

Comment: I suppose "in the same direction" means "to the same side of the curve". This would be true for smooth curves in 2-dimensional manifolds, but not make much sense in higher dimensions. What is the context of the statement you quote, and where did you find it?

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry, yes it is in 2 dimensional space and the system is smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a typo -- they mean "by continuity and intermediate-value theorem", not "by continuity and mean-value theorem".

The argument is that $v(\gamma(t))\times\gamma'(t)$ (the two-dimensional cross product) cannot be zero because $v(x)$ is nonzero, and $\gamma'(t)$ is (implicitly) supposed to be nonzero when saying the curve is smooth. These two nonzero *orthogonal* vectors cannot be parallel so their cross product is nonzero.

Since $v(\gamma(t))\times\gamma'(t)$ is also a *continuous* function of $t$ it cannot have values of different signs in different places without also being zero somewhere between them -- but we've just seen it is never zero.

Comment: Do they really have to be orthagonal? I think it might always be possible to pick some orthagonal but I dont think they have to be.

Comment: @user1: I'm assuming that "transversal curve" _means_ that $v(\gamma(t))$ and $\gamma'(t)$ are orthogonal at every $t$. It it means something else, please edit your question to explain what.

Comment: As far as I understand it only means that they are non parallel. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)

Comment: @user1: I will repeat my invitation to edit that into the question.

Comment: I dont think it matters, your argument is still soild